# how to check value exists in another table

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I have a two tables table_1 and table_2

```
table_1 
  id 
  1
  2
  3
  4
 ...



table_2
     id  table_1_id
     1       1
     5       2
     8       3
     9       4
```

is first I insert table_1 and second table_2. it is insert in php, and when finished transaction it happens that in second table_2 is not inserting row, HOW can I check new inserted value exists in table_2 **IN ORACLE**.

Answer (score 1):

use left join and pick all the ids of table 1 where table2 ids shows null, actually these null ids are not available on table 2

```
select from t1 left join t2 on t1.id=t2.id
 where t.id is null
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to create a function (which returns Boolean - `TRUE` if that `ID` exists in `TABLE_2`; `FALSE` otherwise).

I presume that `TABLE_1_ID` is unique in `TABLE_2`. If it is not, there's a possibility that it'll return `TOO_MANY_ROWS` error so I handled it.

```
create or replace function f_id_exists (par_table_1_id in table_1.id%type)
  return boolean
is
  l_table_1_id    table_1.id%type;
begin
  select t.table_1_id
    into l_table_1_id
    from table_2 t
    where t.table_1_id = par_table_1_id;

  return true;
exception
  when no_data_found then
    return false;
  when too_many_rows then
    return true;
end;
```

Comment: I don't need a function, I want to check it automatically

Comment: You said that you are inserting a row into TABLE_2, and you found out that there's nothing inserted. You could check SQL%ROWCOUNT (should return value larger than 0 if insert succeeded), but - in order to find out whether TABLE_1_ID actually exists in TABLE_2, you need some kind of a SELECT to check that. A function is a *nice* way to do that. What do you call "automatically", exactly?

Comment: automatically, like a trigger

Comment: There's no such thing, I think (not in this case, that is).

Answer (score 0):

You may check with the following Select statement with `INTERSECT` set operation :

```
select id as return_id
  into v_return_id -- this variable of is of table_1.id%type
  from
  (  
   select id from table_1
   intersect
   select table_1_id from table_2 
  ) 
 where id = &i_id -- might be replaced with :new.id or :old.id inside a trigger
```

If for substition variable `i_id` SQL returns a value, then the related `id` doesn't exist, otherwise exists.

Comment: I want to check it automatically, like a trigger

Comment: @MeqenaneriVacharq again the same logic works, you may replace `&i_id` with :new.id as an example